# Umbraco fails to load custom tree definition

Tags: umbraco6

After installing the package newsletter studio, everything works, but the custom tree for Newsletter Studio only shows the main node.
If I check the logs I see the follwoing:
The tree definition:

```
2015-03-25 13:43:01,812 [7] WARN  umbraco.BusinessLogic.ApplicationTree - [Thread 12] The tree definition: <add silent="false" initialize="true" sortOrder="1" alias="newsletterstudio_letter" application="newsletterstudio" title="Newsletters" iconClosed="folder_table.png" iconOpen="folder_table.png" assembly="NewsletterStudio" type="Umbraco.loadNewsletters" action="" /> could not be resolved to a .Net object type
```

In trees.config it says

```
<add silent="false" initialize="true" sortOrder="1" alias="newsletterstudio_letter" application="newsletterstudio" title="Newsletters" iconClosed="folder_table.png" iconOpen="folder_table.png" assembly="NewsletterStudio" type="Umbraco.loadNewsletters" action="" />
```

I have this exact same site running elsewhere as well, without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a bug in the way how Umbraco handles the configuration in tree.config in 6.2.5

The issue is filed here: http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-6509#tab=Comments

Specificly for Newsletter Studio, this can be solved by changing the tree.config manually.

The entries for Newsletter Studio should read:

```
<add silent="false" initialize="true" sortOrder="1" alias="newsletterstudio_letter" application="newsletterstudio" title="Newsletters" iconClosed="folder_table.png" iconOpen="folder_table.png" assembly="NewsletterStudio" type="NewsletterStudio.Umbraco.loadNewsletters, NewsletterStudio" action="" />

  <add silent="false" initialize="true" sortOrder="3" alias="newsletterstudio_settings" application="newsletterstudio" title="Settings" iconClosed="settingMasterDatatype.gif" iconOpen="settingMasterDatatype.gif" assembly="NewsletterStudio" type="NewsletterStudio.Umbraco.loadSettings, NewsletterStudio" action="" />

  <add silent="false" initialize="true" sortOrder="2" alias="newsletterstudio_subscriptions" application="newsletterstudio" title="Subscriptions" iconClosed="group.png" iconOpen="group.png" assembly="NewsletterStudio" type="NewsletterStudio.Umbraco.loadSubscriptions, NewsletterStudio" action="" />
```

More info: https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/newsletter-studio/comments/63530-Newsletter-content-tree-fails-to-load#

I imagine that other packages will suffer from this issue as well. I know for a fact that Contour has this problem as well.